# PHP How to get data from multiple level array

Tags: php, json

I have this array from JSON file and I want to get data from **[url]**. Array is saved as variable `$data`.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [images] => Array
    (
            [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                    [startdate] => 20190625
                    [fullstartdate] => 201906250700
                    [enddate] => 20190626
                    [url] => /th?id=OHR.SutherlandFalls_ROW5711472757_1920x1080.jpg&rf=LaDigue_1920x1080.jpg&pid=hp
            )
    )
)
```

Result should be like:

```
echo $data[0]->url; will show the link/value /th?id=...
```

Comment: `$data->images[0]->url`

Comment: Thanks @Alex Howansky, couldn't figure it for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$data` variable is not an array, it's an instance of `stdClass`. Therefore, you can retrieve it like this:

```
$data->images[0]->url;
```